# Locale problems Belgium English

Tags: locale

My goal is to install Kubuntu in English language in Belgium.

Ok, let's start from installation.

Choose Belgian keyboard.

[image: screenshot]

Region: Europe, Time zone: Belgium.

[image: screenshot]

The installation is done. This is the first login screen. But... Why is it telling me the time in German?

[image: screenshot]

Let's try fixing it and set everything in Belgium English!

[image: screenshot]

After a reboot is the time still in German.

[image: screenshot]

When I run `sudo apt upgrade`. A nasty locale error passes by.

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "en_BE.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_BE.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "de_BE.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "de_BE.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "de_BE.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_BE.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_BE.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "en_BE.UTF-8",
        LC_PAPER = "de_BE.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_BE.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

`sudo locale-gen en_BE` outputs `Error: 'en_BE' is not a supported language or locale`

Why is it doing this and is it fixable?

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~$ cat /etc/default/locale
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_BE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_BE.UTF-8"


user@user-virtual-machine:~$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_BE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_BE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_BE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_BE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_BE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_BE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_BE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_BE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_BE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_BE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_BE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_BE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_BE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: The problem is that no en_BE locale exists in glibc, which provides the locales in Ubuntu (including Kubuntu).

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output of these two commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/locale` 2. `locale`

Comment: Here you go, thank you for your time! @GunnarHjalmarsson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using Kubuntu, and am not too familiar with the KDE way to handle languages and locales.

However, given the information above, one way to (almost) achieve the desired behavior is to pretend that you are Danish. :)

So my suggestion is that you change the overall *Region* setting to **Denmark - English**. That will give you ISO compatible date and time formats.

Then you may want to change the *Currency* setting to **Belgium - German** to get the Belgium currency symbol.

Those changes won't affect the login screen, though. To fix the login screen you can open the `/etc/default/locale` file for editing, remove all the settings of `LC_*` variables, and only keep the setting of `LANG`.

HTH

Comment: This works, but when I run `locale` I says: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory. [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/5pzAB8xK)

Also, should I still set currency to Belgium - German when my native language is Belgium Flemish?

So is your suggestion to set everything except the region (most upper) setting to Belgium - German?

Comment: Oh, you probably mean to set it to 'No change'. Then the error is gone! Thanks!

Comment: [This works](https://i.imgur.com/32Z5Nix.png)

Comment: @MatMis: Right, that's what I meant. Glad to hear that it solved the problem for you. (Personally I consider the KDE GUI buggy, since it lets you set language/country combinations which are not represented by existing locales.)